# ErrorException copy() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: laravel

I have this issue in a laravel script hosted on a server. I am getting this issue.

ErrorException: Warning: copy() has been disabled for security reasons.

Whene I try to update the script on the server from version to another version.

Answer (score 0):

As per knowledge, have a look at your php.ini file, and look for the disable-functions directive. If you see `copy` listed there, then that is the cause of the error.

Remove `copy` from this setting, and restart your php service.

See [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) reference in the PHP Manual